# Estimates norms with norm of their sum by Banach's isomorphism theorem if Banach space is sum of two linear subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087631/if-banach-space-is-algebraic-sum-of-its-two-linear-subspaces-with-mutually-separ?rq=1) and thinking about some passage that said to estimates norms with norm of their sum by Banach's isomorphism theorem.
Rewriting that for this:

> Let X be a Banach space and let $X_1,X_2 \subset X$ be two closed linear subspaces such that $X=X_1\oplus X_2$, i.e. $X1 \cap X2=\{0\}$ and every vector $x \in X$ can be written as $x=x_1+x_2$ with $x_1 \in X_1$ and $x_2 \in X_2$.
> Then there is a constant $C>0$ such that
> $$\|x_1\| + \|x_2\| \leq C \|x_1 + x_2\|, \quad \forall x_1 \in X_2, \, x_2 \in X_2.$$

After research, my doubt is, how I can proof this inequality using banach isomorphism theorem?

Thanks for any help :)

Edit: Using algorithm of [geetha290krm](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1064504/geetha290krm) I wrote

- Let us verify that $X_1 \times X_2$ with $\|(x_1,x_2)\|= \|x_1\| + \|x_2\|$ is a Banach space.
  Supose $\{(x_{1,n}, x_{2,n})\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset X_1 \times X_2$ a cauchy sequence, by definition
  $$\forall \varepsilon>0, \, \exists n_\varepsilon = n(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N} : \|(x_{1,n}, x_{2,n}) - (x_{1,m}, x_{2,m})\| < \varepsilon, \quad m,n > n_\varepsilon.$$
  So
  $$\|(x_{1,n}, x_{2,n}) - (x_{1,m}, x_{2,m})\| = \|x_{1,n}-x_{1,m}\| - \|x_{2,n}-x_{2,m}\|.$$
  Closed Subspace of Banach Space forms Banach Space, then $(X_1,\|\cdot\|_{X_1})$ and $(X_2,\|\cdot\|_{X_2})$ are Banach spaces. And then
  $$\exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N} : \|x_{1,n}-x_{1,m}\| < \varepsilon/2, \quad m,n > N_1.$$
  $$\exists N_2 \in \mathbb{N} : \|x_{2,n}-x_{2,m}\| < \varepsilon/2, \quad m,n > N_2.$$
  Taking $N = \max \{N_1,N_2\}$ we have
  $$\|(x_{1,n}, x_{2,n}) - (x_{1,m}, x_{2,m})\| = \|x_{1,n}-x_{1,m}\| - \|x_{2,n}-x_{2,m}\| < \varepsilon, \quad m,n > N.$$
  Therefore $X_1 \times X_2$ is a Banach space with norm $\|(x_1,x_2)\|= \|x_1\| + \|x_2\|$.
- Let the map $T:X_1 \times X_2 \to X$ defined by $T(x_1,x_2) = x_1 + x_2$. We will show that map is a continuous bijection.
  We have
  $$T(x_1,x_2) = 0 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x_1+x_2=0.$$
  How $X_1 \cap X_2 = \{0\}$ implies $x_1 \neq -x_2$ and vice versa vice versa since they do not share elements or inverses, so $x_1=x_2=0$. Then $N (T) = \{0\}$ with implies $T$ injective.
  Also $\dim X = \dim N (T) + \dim R(T)$ and $\dim X = \dim R(T)$, so is surjective too.
  So
  $$\|T(x_1,x_2)\| = \|x_1+x_2\| \leq \|x_1\| + \|x_2\| = \|(x_1,x_2)\|.$$
  and then $T$ is limited.
- We will apply the Banach isomorphism theorem.
  How $T: X_1 \times X_2 \to X$ is a bijective continuous operator,$X_1 \times X_2$ is a Banach space with norm $\|(x_1,x_2)\|= \|x_1\| + \|x_2\|$  and $X$ too, by the Banach isomorphism theorem $T$ is a isomorphism.
- The inverse of $T$ is like $T^{-1}(x_1+x_2)=(x_1,x_2)$. By previous item $T^{-1}$ is limited, i.e.
  $$\|T^{-1}(x_1+x_2)\| \leq C \|x_1+x_2\|$$
  with implies
  $$\|(x_1,x_2)\| = \|x_1\| + \|x_2\| \leq C \|x_1+x_2\|.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step I: Verify that $X_1\times X_2$ with $\|(x_1,x_2)\|=\|x_1\|+\|x_2\|$ is Banach space.

Step II: Consider the map  $T:X_1\times X_2 \to X$ defined by $T(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$. Show that this is a bijective linear map and that it is continuous.

Step II Apply the theorem to see that this map has a   continuous inverse.

Step IV: Write down the definition of boundeness of the inverse.